# Paypal Integration with struts2

Tags: java, ssl, paypal, pki

I am trying to integrate paypal. I followed all the steps given in this link: [Paypal Integration Wizard](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecdigitalgoods/code.php).

When I click on the Paypal button I get the error as:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
```

After going though the forums I added this piece of code:

```
static public void doTrustToCertificates() throws Exception {
    try{
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws CertificateException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String urlHostName, SSLSession session) {
                if (!urlHostName.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getPeerHost())) {
                    System.out.println("Warning: URL host '" + urlHostName + "' is different to SSLSession host '" + session.getPeerHost() + "'.");
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And Called the method just before calling an URL. Now I get a different exception stating that

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.paypal.actions.PaypalFunctions.httpcall(PaypalFunctions.java:297)
    at com.paypal.actions.PaypalFunctions.setExpressCheckout(PaypalFunctions.java:151)
    at com.paypal.actions.Checkout.doGet(Checkout.java:72)
    at com.paypal.actions.Checkout.doPost(Checkout.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
```

Comment: Just bike shedding: your `X509TrustManager` implementation is dangerous. It effectively turns off all the checks for the server's identity. You won't know who you are talking with. The folks using your site really deserve more effort, especially if they are providing financial information. See [The Most Dangerous Code in the World: Validating SSL Certificates in Non-Browser Software](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

After doing 4-5 days of research I understood that the firewall in the company stopping to access. I tried with my home network and I could able to do it. I will post my version shortly with all the necessary code.